# Git folder gets damaged

Tags: git

I cloned a Git repository to my disk, it is a branch

```
git clone -b branchname git-remote-repo.path.git branchname
```

Everything works, I can commit the changes and push to the remote repo.

I work with VS Code and no git support, I use git from commandline.

Then, from time to time, I dont know what causes it, my .git folder gets corrupted and I get an error when I run a git command inside of my folder like git status- I get

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

What can cause this, e.g. changing a working folder in VS Code?

The .git folder is still there but folder like logs or objects are removed.

More info:

- OS : Windows 10
- I dont use this as dynamic folder
- I do the git command inside of the folder that I cloned
- I removed now the github extension from VS code and it didnt happen again til now :-)
- I had the feeling that changing the working folder in VS code could lead to the problem

Some hours later:-)
And now I have it again, I commited, I pushed to the remote repo, all fine. I developed on it using VS Code, no github extesnion anymore, and then this:

```
C:\Projekte\Blender\Addons\fast-carve-2-8>git commit -a
[fast-carve-2-8 ec4e43d] sharpness 60 degree for bevel
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

C:\Projekte\Blender\Addons\fast-carve-2-8>git push origin fast-carve-2-8
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 330 bytes | 330.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), completed with 2 local objects.
To https://github.com/jayanam/fast-carve.git
   2c729eb..ec4e43d  fast-carve-2-8 -> fast-carve-2-8

C:\Projekte\Blender\Addons\fast-carve-2-8>git status
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Comment: Is there some sort of “clean” operation being run that would remove the directory? I’m afraid without substantially more detail, it will be nigh-impossible to identify the root cause and solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, you haven't provided enough information for us to provide a helpful answer. For example, what operating system are you using? Is the repository saved in a Dropbox folder, or similar? Please read [ask].

Comment: It's hard to say for sure without more information, but a common cause for this sort of problem is putting the clone into a shared or dynamic folder (such as Dropbox or a shared-folder provided by a virtual computer manager). Git desperately needs to be in full, complete, 100% control of the `.git` directory without having some Smart(Alec) Sharing System going in and fiddling with the knobs.

Comment: what directory are you executing `git status` from? can you execute a `pwd` and paste the path here? you can only execute git commands from inside a git project. for example: if i cloned a repo named "xyz" at location C:/user/ then i can execute git commands from only within "C:/user/xyz*". check if you not doing anything differently !

Comment: Happened again, see my modification of the original post.